# How to get the selectManyCheckbox value in my bean using valueChangeListener?

Tags: java, netbeans, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

I am trying to get the user select value to my backing bean. I've posted my XHTML code below:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox  style="z-index: 1000" id="gencount" layout="grid" columns="1" valueChangeListener="#{subUserBean.degreeFilter}">
    <p:ajax event="click"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="All" itemLabel="All"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="BE" itemLabel="BE"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="B.TECH" itemLabel="B.TECH"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="MCA" itemLabel="MCA"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Value change listener in my bean:

```
public void degreeFilter(ValueChangeEvent dege) {
    System.out.println("Select degree-->"+dege.getNewValue().toString());
}
```

I am getting only the object value as "[Ljava.lang.String;@a33ca7", but I need the select value as "BE".

Comment: You are using p:selectManyCheckbox.Because of you get array of strings.

Comment: Try to cast dege to String[] and print it with for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void degreeFilter(ValueChangeEvent dege) {  
    Object[] objArr = (Object[])dege.getNewValue();
    for (int x = 0; x < objArr.length; x++)
    {
        Object obj = objArr[x]; 
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
        degree=obj.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this intended to be a solution, or additional information regarding the question? If it's the former, please [mark it as the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after the 48-hour waiting period. If it's the latter, please edit the question rather than posting an answer.

Comment: this is the answer which i have found @AdiInbar

Comment: In that case, please mark it as accepted tomorrow. BTW, you should always include tags from the main language(s) involved in the question, otherwise your question won't be seen by most people who answer questions for those languages.